I have 2 ftp users in ubuntu and chroot them to their home directories. Can't login if /bin/false or /sbin/nologin
I have an FTP server configured using vsftpd and created 2 users.
ftpuser1
ftpuser2
these are chrooted to their /home directories.
I cannot login into ftp if i changed the shell of the user accounts to /sbin/nologin

I wasn't too happy with just commenting out the offending check, so I changed my answer to outline a better way to fix this

On Ubuntu 24.04 at least (this probably applies to previous Ubuntu versions as well): vsftpd's default PAM policy is to deny access to users whose shell is not listed in /etc/shells (and /sbin/nologin is not listed in /etc/shells).
/etc/pam.d/vsftpd:
# Standard behaviour for ftpd(8).
auth    required        pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/ftpusers onerr=succeed

# Note: vsftpd handles anonymous logins on its own. Do not enable pam_ftp.so.

# Standard pam includes
@include common-account
@include common-session
@include common-auth
auth    required        pam_shells.so

Users with a shell set to /sbin/nologin (or to any shell not listed in /etc/shells) will be denied access because of this check:
auth    required        pam_shells.so

While this could be fixed in multiple ways, the optimal way IMO would be to add the following just before the offending check:
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]    pam_succeed_if.so       shell = /sbin/nologin

So that /etc/pam.d/vsftpd ends up looking like this:
# Standard behaviour for ftpd(8).
auth    required        pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/ftpusers onerr=succeed

# Note: vsftpd handles anonymous logins on its own. Do not enable pam_ftp.so.

# Standard pam includes
@include common-account
@include common-session
@include common-auth
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]    pam_succeed_if.so       shell = /sbin/nologin
auth    required        pam_shells.so

What the addition does is:

Invoking pam_succeed_if.so, which will succeed if the user's shell is set to /sbin/nologin and
Skipping the following auth check if pam_succeed_if.so succeded, ignoring the outcome of the module otherwise.

